# Static polymorphism with generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I was hoping to create some clean code that can recursively dig into a collection and print the first Integer it finds. Coming from a C++ background that approach looked like this:

```
class Test {
static void print(Integer i) {
  System.out.println(i);
}

static <T> void print(ArrayList<T> arr) {
  T entry= arr.at(0);
  Test.print (entry);
}

static void Test() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayOfArrayOfInt= create();
    print( arrayOfArrayOfInt );
}
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

One alternative is to give up on static polymorphism and create a function print(Object o) and then do a number of instanceof checks to branch to the right behavior. Is that the only way it can be done due to Java's type erasure or is there a more elegant approach?

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it isn't working?

Comment: Easier to focus on the polymorphism behavior if you can cut out the extraneous errors (`get()` vs `at()`, missing `create()`, missing imports) and post a compiling, running example. Here's a version I got to run; I think it makes the dispatch issue a bit more clear.  https://gist.github.com/apjanke/aa8583e2f36c0955589c

Comment: Sorry about the wrong method name. I intentionally omitted create() because it adds a lot of noise. Thank you for creating the gist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method will recursively dig into an `Object` and return an `Optional` containing the first `Integer` it finds, or `Optional.empty()` if it can't find one.

```
static Optional<Integer> firstInt(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Integer)
        return Optional.of((Integer) o);
    if (o instanceof int[]) {
        int[] array = (int[]) o;
        return array.length > 0 ? Optional.of(array[0]) : Optional.empty();
    }
    if (o instanceof Object[])
        return firstInt(Arrays.asList((Object[]) o));
    if (o instanceof Iterable) {
        for (Object o2 : (Iterable<?>) o) {
            Optional<Integer> result = firstInt(o2);
            if (result.isPresent())
                return result;
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

You *can* do this using polymorphism, but you would have to create an interface `Searchable` like this

```
interface Searchable {
    Optional<Integer> search();
}
```

and then create wrapper classes for all the concrete types you want to be able to search. For example:

```
public final class SearchableList<T extends Searchable> extends AbstractList<T> implements Searchable {

    private final List<T> list;

    SearchableList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    // rest omitted
}
```

However, this would be such a convoluted mess, and I would avoid it, preferring the `instanceof` checks instead.

Comment: If this `firstInt()` is intending to handle all the array cases, it's missing cases for `o instanceof Integer[]` and `o instanceof Number[]` (because arrays are not covariant with their element types). I would stick with just the `Collections` types; mixing collections and arrays is a pain.

Comment: @AndrewJanke Arrays are covariant. Try `System.out.println(new Integer[3] instanceof Object[]);`

Comment: Holy cow, you're right. How did I get *that* wrong?

Comment: @AndrewJanke It's unbelievably confusing because arrays and generics work in totally different ways. What I find inexplicable is that `Object[]` doesn't implement `Iterable` so you need a separate case for that.

Comment: Thank you. The current approach in our source uses a simpler version of what you described. I foresee people trying to pass all kinds of bad data to the function (List<String>, Bitmap, whathaveyou) so it would have been nice to enforce arguments at compile-time rather than rely on runtime instanceof checks. But it looks like that's not feasible.

Comment: @Cross_ That's ok. I guess you could make the method throw an exception rather than return an empty optional if the user passes completely the wrong type, but a compile-time check is not going to be feasible, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

You're right in assuming that you can't treat java generics as you would a c++ template.

So, without `instanceof`, this will not guess that entry is an Integer (neither in runtime nor in compile time):

```
static <T> void print(ArrayList<T> arr) {
  T entry= arr.get(0);
  Test.print (entry);
}
```

So to *"to create some clean code that can recursively dig into a collection and print the first Integer it find"* (or rather the first non list element at index 0) in java:

```
static void print(Object obj) {
    System.out.println(obj);
}

static <T> void print(List<T> arr) {
    T entry = arr.get(0);
    if (entry instanceof List)
        print((List<?>) entry);
    else 
        print(entry);
}

static void test() {
    List<List<Integer>> arrayOfArrayOfInt = create();
    print(arrayOfArrayOfInt);
}
```

Not the elegant solution you'd like but the feasible solution the generic type system requires.

Comment: I think this explanation is a little off. Without `instanceof` and casts, the compiler *does* guess what to do with that parameterized `print(ArrayList<T> arr)` entry: it treats `T` as `Object`, attempts to call `Test.print(Object)`, which doesn't exist, and you get a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yep, give up on static polymorphism and use `instanceof`. Or just write a local loop to do your work.

Java's generics are much weaker than C++'s templates. In particular, the compiler will not produce new specializations for you. All you can do with them is do more restrictive static type checking on classes and methods that are already defined through normal means (e.g. you wrote them out by hand or generated them with a tool). As you suspected, type erasure is relevant.

With Java generics, this code:

```
static <T> void print(ArrayList<T> arr) {
  T entry= arr.at(0);
  Test.print (entry);
}
```

always effectively turns in to this, due to type erasure:

```
static Object void print(ArrayList<Object> arr) {
  Object entry= arr.at(0);
  Test.print (entry);
}
```

It will not produce separate specializations as C++ templates would.

Your particular piece of code isn't working because it's missing a couple particular methods, which you'd have to supply by hand. But I think I can see where you're trying to go. (I assume you want to end up with code that's going to work on a broader range of types than just `List<List<Integer>>`.) And you're not going to get a satisfactory solution for that using Java generics. (You *can* make it work, but you'll have to write a whole lot of code by hand, which templates won't help you with. And there would be some grody edge cases.) Switch to dynamic type checking and `instanceof`; that's the Java way to do this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the function to get an element is "get" not "at." However, your main problem is that you are trying to call the function "print" which takes an integer, but passing it a value of type "T."

If you are going to call print and pass it a value of unknown type, the function must either take an argument of type Object or take a generic argument, such as

```
public <T> void print(T item)
```

or

```
public void print (Object item)
```

Java will only match function calls to the most specific overload at compile time, if you're trying to find the correct overload at runtime you will have to use instanceof. Alternatively, you could build a HashMap that points from Class objects to Consumer objects.

```
HashMap<Class<?>, Consumer<?>> prints = new HashMap<>();
void setup() {
    prints.put(ArrayList.class, (list) -> {
        for (Object o : list) {
            print(o);
        }
    }

    prints.put(Integer.class, (integer) -> System.out.println(integer));
}

void print(Object o) {
    Consumer<?> func = prints.get(o.getClass());
    func.accept(o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep this code the way it is, you'll have to add another print-method for objects.

```
public static void print(Object o){}
```

But there are better approaches for your example anyways.